# Reading Xml with Javascript on an offline application?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

It seems to me that in order for the javascript to read the xml document it has to be hosted on a web server. It wont read the xml doc otherwise, is there any way i can read xml documents with javascript on an offline application like say a html page on my desktop? any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Going back a while and not necessarily working in modern browsers XML could be loaded into an XML data island within an HTML document and manipulated by a client side XMLDOM. This is only really viable in an environment where you can predict Microsoft browsers and platform. See  here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766512(v=vs.85).aspx and http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp

It seems that this technology is updated, but I couldn't vouch for it working on non MS platforms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760399.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Browsers usually have settings that enable local file access - some old browsers actually had enabled it by default - just browse settings on your particular browser.

This should be sufficient for personal use.

Possible workarounds:

1. Use XML strings instead of

   ```
   var xmlString=
   '
   //some XML content
   ';
   ```

and then load loadXMLString(). If motivation of using XML was to simply have XML representation of data, then it should not be very problematic to have XML definition within HTML/JavaScript document as a string.

1. If you truly need or want to get XML data from local files regardless of browser's preferences then self-signed java applets are good choice. Users will need allow them to run, but then with some Java applet method you can load an XML file and return its content - Java applet method can be run from Javascript. Of course users must have Java installed in this case.

Another option just for Microsoft browsers (and possibly other with ActiveX support) is an ActiveX object with similar capabilities.